# Reinitializing the state of gridview after changes done

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How can I reinitialize the state of the GridView structure?

For instance, I have defined a set of BoundFields in my aspx page, however, the columns' names and its visibility changes accordingly to conditions.

How can I reset the whole GridView structure, including its column names and visibility to the one I have defined in my aspx page?

Is there a way to do so? Is there a general function to do such or must I define a new function to reset each and every column back to its original state considering I do not only have one Gridview with at least 30 columns in each.

EDIT:

FOR EXAMPLE:

IN MY .ASPX PAGE:

```
<ASP:GRIDVIEW RUNAT='SERVER' ID='GVEXAMPLE'>
    <ASP:BOUNDFIELD HEADERTEXT="ABC" />
    <ASP:BOUNDFIELD HEADERTEXT="DEF" />
    <ASP:BOUNDFIELD HEADERTEXT="GHI" />
</ASP:GRIDVIEW>
```

IN MY .ASPX.CS PAGE:

```
GVEXAMPLE.Columns[1].HeaderText = "this is my new header text";
```

IS THERE A PREDEFINED FUNCTION IN C# THAT I CAN USE TO RESET THE HEADERTEXT BACK TO ITS ORIGINAL NAMING, 'DEF'?

OR DO I HAVE TO DEFINE MY OWN FUNCTIONS TO RESET ITS NAMING LIKE

```
GVEXAMPLE.Columns[1].HeaderText = "DEF";
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: I have already stated my example in the passage.

Comment: you obviously did not read what i posted - how about reading this: You may find this link useful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask